# Extending the Arrays-class in Java

Tags: java, arrays, extends

I'm trying to add functionality to the Arrays-class. In my project I use the (static) methods from Arrays and have some other methods that also handle array-conversion, sorting, etc...

I'm trying to add these to an object MyArrays that extends Arrays so I can go

```
MyArrays.toList(foo);
```

but also

```
MyArrays.myOwnFunction(bar);
```

but i'm not able to extend it because Arrays-contructor has private access.
I know it's not really necessary, but now I know i'm unable to do it, I realy want to.
Is there any workaround for this?

thanks,

Comment: What Arrays-class are we talking about here? Neither `java.util.Arrays` nor `java.lang.reflect.Array` contain a `toList` method. However, since the reflect version is `final`, you can't extend it. And since both classes consist solely of `static` methods, do you really need to extend the class anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. And why would it matter whether you have the utility functions in one or in two classes? For the record - there is commons-lang's `ArrayUtils` that has additional utility methods.

Technically, you can reimplement all methods in your utility class by simply calling the corresponding methods in `Arrays`, but that's unneeded.

Comment: And why can't you? I know its def constructor is `private` so you physically can't extend `Arrays`, but what's the reasoning behind it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try using the Trove4j library.  This has collections which support primitives has many of the useful Arrays/Collections methods added, like sort().  They can also be extended.